# Bipartite proof

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph of order $5$ or more. Prove that at most one of $G$ and "$G$ complement" is bipartite.

I'm lost as to what needs to be done. I know that A nontrivial graph $G$ is bipartite if and only if $G$ contains no odd cycles.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is the fact that, if $G$ is a graph of order $n$, then $\chi(G)\chi(\overline G)\ge n$. To see this observe that, if $V=V(G)=V(\overline G)$, and if $f:V\to[h]$ is a proper coloring of $G$ and $g:V\to[k]$ is a proper coloring of $\overline G$, then $x\mapsto(f(x),g(x))$ is a one-to-one map from $V$ to $[h]\times[k]$.

Now, if $G$ is a graph of order $n$, and if $G$ and $\overline G$ are bipartite graphs, then $n\le\chi(G)\chi(\overline G)\le2\cdot2=4$.

Answer (score 3):

Let me give you a hint towards a much, much more elementary solution:

**Hint:** It is enough to show that if $G$ is bipartite, then $\bar{G}$ (the complement of $G$) is not bipartite.

To that end, suppose that $V(G)=A\cup B$ is a bipartition of $G$.  Then in $E(G)$, there are no edges inside $A$, no edges inside $B$, and there may be some edges between $A$ and $B$.

Based on this, what does $E(\bar{G})$ look like? Since $G$ contains no edges inside $A$ and no edges inside $B$, it must be the case that $\bar{G}$ contains EVERY edge inside $A$ and EVERY edge inside $B$.

So, if $\bar{G}$ WERE bipartite, it couldn't be the case that any two vertices from $A$ or any two vertices from $B$ fell in the same part of the bipartition.

Can you see how to finish it from here, using the assumption that there are at least 5 vertices distributed between $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 2):

What is needed here is Ramsey's theorem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_theorem

In particular, Ramsey's theorem says that every Graph with 6 or more vertices either has a clique of size three, or its complement has a clique of size three.

Comment: But the question was about graphs with $5$ or more vertices.

Comment: Yes, the case $n=5$ has to be dealt with separately. Your solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Assume one of them is bipartite. So, at least one of parts has 3 or more vertices. Let's pick 3 of them and call them u, v, w. As these 3 vertices are in the same part, they have no connection.  Therefore, in the complement graph there are uv, uw and vw edges. Now, u, v, w, u is a cycle of length 3 and it shows that complement graph could not be bipartite.